# Cat Detection Using Haar Training

Tags: opencv

I would like to detect deformable objects (a CAT in my case) , using HAAR- cascades . I ran the test on 2000 positives and 3000 negative images upto 20 stages . I don't see anything expected happening. 
I am sure it might be the problem of my training data set. My positive data set has the  cat images in it . In different shapes and postures of the same cat  . I wonder if Haar would be able to recognize the differences in the positive data set , and still recognize them as cats.

Need help , Is there any other alternative method that I could use ??

Comment: There is a paper about cat detection: [Cats and Dogs, Parkhi, CVPR 2012](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/publications/2012/parkhi12a/). Maybe you can get some ideas from them. For example the authors decided, cat bodies are not well captured by such stiff models. There approach was to detect only the head and then find the rest of the body using segmentation.

Comment: Have you succeed creating the cat detecting algorithm using Haar training? I'm also having the same issue for now :-) Thanks!

Comment: No, I don't think haar works well with deformable object recognition. At least, I couldn't get it to run in my case, too many false negatives / positives. I also tried the Bag of words method for object recognition, they do pretty good on rigid objects but not on cats. Very difficult to capture all of the variability in the data while training the classifier. In the end we cheated and settled for a very trivial approach of color histogram matching, no way close to what we intended to do but enough to complete the class project.

Answer (score 4):

First off, you haven't listed what you are using to train your haar classifiers. If you are not using opencv_traincascades this is the place to start.

Secondly detecting a cat is a very difficult job, there are a lot of undefiend edges, rotational and spatial variances. using this train of thought, answer these questions to yourself:

- What does your positive dataset look like?
- Is this similar to what you are showing through the input feed
- What is the false alarm rate of your classifier when you have trained it?
- What are you including in your background set (more images that look like cats that arn't cats are better etc)

I would suggest posting your output into the question from the classifying stages in order for us to get a better view of what is happening. Take a look at these links for more help.

Maybe try with pens, or logos first, follow the openCV tutorials and understand the basics? (sorry if I have assumed you don't know the basics if you do)

G./